# Calculating min/max of data points on 'y axis' -highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to calculate the min max for the data points, my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4NxYh/108/
I tried setting the `min` and `max` values to "null" as per the docs of highcharts-http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max, but not sure how this one works exactly..

```
 yAxis: {
        min: null,
        max: null

}
```

Ideas/help appreciated!Thanks

Comment: can you explain bit more what behavior you want is not achived

Comment: If you do not want to have max/min calculated by the chart you need to calculate max/min on your own http://jsfiddle.net/u79c8L4p/